# Unity - chained dependencies with overridden parameter

Tags: c#, unity-container

I need to override parameter on a chained dependencies. My overridden parameter has to be passed to first and second instantiated classes.

So my client class need an instance of `IA` with a custom `env` parameter (not know at startup). And the constructor of `IA` need an instance of `IB` with the same custom `env` parameter.

So here is the code of my two classes :

```
class A : IA
{
    IB _b;
    AppEnv _env;

    public A(IB b, AppEnv env)
    {
        _b = b;
        _env = env;
    }

    void DoStuff();
}

class B : IB
{
    AppEnv _env;

    public A(AppEnv env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    void DoStuff();
}
```

And here is the code of my client :

```
var env = new... // "good" env, with runtime values
var a = container.Resolve<IA>(new ParameterOverride("env", env));
```

Instance of `IA` has the "good" `env` parameter. But how can I pass this parameter to instance of `IB` ?

My Unity configuration look like this :

```
var defaultEnv = new ... // default env object
container.RegisterType<IB, B>(new InjectionConstructor(defaultEnv));
container.RegisterType<IA, A>(new InjectionConstructor(defaultEnv));
```

Comment: I suggest a Base class that inherits AppEnv instead of override with Unity.

Comment: Could you not just get your `b` using the same method as you are getting a in your code and then override both parameters when getting a? I've not used unity but from just looking at your code it looks like it should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change inheritance, I think you shouldnt use static resolution for the `InjectionConstructor` in Unity. I'd go with `ResolvedParameter`:

```
// At "Startup"
container.RegisterType<IA, A>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<AppEnv>("JustANameIfYouHaveMany")));

container.RegisterType<IB, B>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<AppEnv>("JustANameIfYouHaveMany")));

// Whenever you can get the proper value of AppEnv
AppEnv correctValue = AppEnv.WhateverLogic();
container.RegisterInstance<AppEnv>("JustANameIfYouHaveMany", correctValue);
```

With what I wrote, you can do the startup registration the earliest you can, but as long as you do the second part of the registrations before you `container.Resolve<IA or IB>()`, it's going resolve fine.